# Laravel Backpack eCommerce - Demo data

Tags: laravel

I am following the [eStarter - ecommerce on Laravel](https://github.com/updivision/estarter-ecommerce-for-laravel) README.md and ran into an issue trying to seed the database:

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

The seeders don't create all the table columns necessary to navigate the admin. 
Does anyone have a dummy SQL dump I can manually import? This way I can hit the ground running!

Many thanks

Comment: Have you checked the log?

Comment: Have you try: https://github.com/avored/laravel-ecommerce

Answer (score 1):

Found an ER diagram [image: ER diagram] from their [github](https://github.com/updivision/estarter-ecommerce-for-laravel)

All good :)